# Magento 2: Can't Override Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodManagement

Tags: overriding, magento2

I am trying to override Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodManagement to intercept a bug with shipping address thrown in the apply function.

My `app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend/di.xml` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodMangement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\ShippingMethodMangement" />
</config>
```

and `app/code/Vendor/Model/Rewrite/ShippingMethodManagement.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Address as QuoteAddressResource;

/**
 * Shipping method read service
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class ShippingMethodManagement extends \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement implements
    \Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagementInterface,
    ShipmentEstimationInterface
{
    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * Shipping method converter
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter
     */
    protected $converter;

    /**
     * Customer Address repository
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $addressRepository;

    /**
     * @var Quote\TotalsCollector
     */
    protected $totalsCollector;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor
     */
    private $dataProcessor;

    /**
     * @var AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory
     */
    private $addressFactory;

    /**
     * @var QuoteAddressResource
     */
    private $quoteAddressResource;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param Cart\ShippingMethodConverter $converter
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param Quote\TotalsCollector $totalsCollector
     * @param AddressInterfaceFactory|null $addressFactory
     * @param QuoteAddressResource|null $quoteAddressResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter $converter,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector $totalsCollector,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory = null,
        QuoteAddressResource $quoteAddressResource = null
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->converter = $converter;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->totalsCollector = $totalsCollector;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(AddressInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->quoteAddressResource = $quoteAddressResource ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(QuoteAddressResource::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */

    public function apply($cartId, $carrierCode, $methodCode)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        if (0 == $quote->getItemsCount()) {
            throw new InputException(
                __('The shipping method can\'t be set for an empty cart. Add an item to cart and try again.')
            );
        }
        if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                __('The Cart includes virtual product(s) only, so a shipping address is not used.')
            );
        }
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

        if (!$shippingAddress->getCountryId()) {
            // Remove empty quote address
            $this->quoteAddressResource->delete($shippingAddress);
            throw new StateException(__('*** The shipping address is missing. Set the address and try again.'));
        }
        $shippingAddress->setShippingMethod($carrierCode . '_' . $methodCode);
    }

}
```

I have run rm -r var/generated, s:up, s:d:c, c:f, s:s:d

No errors are thrown on compile but the model override doesn't work. The apply method is not hit in this file and is still run from `Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement`

Can anyone explain why this override isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the di.xml in the following path:

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodMangement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\ShippingMethodMangement" />
</config>
```

Comment: the di.xml is in that path. I have tried both and neither are working

Comment: Did you copy my code directly? if you've changed the folder from /etc/frontend to just /etc, then you need to also fix the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation as yours is relative to the folder its in.